# If an affine algebraic set $X$ is irreducible and it is isomorphic to another algebraic set $Y$, is $Y$ also irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is from Algebraic geometry text by Shafarevich:

> **Definition** A regular map $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ of closed sets is an *isomorphism* if it has an inverse, that is, if there exists a regular map $g\colon Y \rightarrow X$ such that $f\circ g = 1$ and $g \circ f = 1$. In this case we say that $X$ and $Y$ are *isomorphic*.

At first, it would seem like isomorphism should preserve properties like the irreducibility of algebraic sets so if $X$ can/cannot be written as the union of two proper closed sets, then the same should be true for set $Y$, but when I tried to prove this, I realize that isomorphisms do not have to map open/closed sets to open/ closed sets as those are topological properties so does that mean the claim I made is not true?

Comment: If $X$ is irreducible, then the ideal $I(X)$ is prime. For $X\cong Y$, also $I(Y)$ is prime, so that $Y$ is irreducible.

Comment: What do you mean by "isomorphisms do not have to map open/closed sets to open/ closed sets as those are topological properties"? Regular maps are continuous, so an isomorphism is always a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a regular map $f$ induces (contravariantly) a homomorphism $f^{*} :K[Y] \to K[X] $, Since $f$ is an. Isomorphism, there's $g$ st:$g\circ f=f\circ g=I$, So $g^{*} \circ f^{*} =f^{*} \circ g^{*} =I$, hence $K[Y] $ is ring isomorphic $K[X] $, hence they are either both integral domains or non integral domains, which is equivalent to saying that both $X, Y$ are irreducible or both non irreducible.